# what is the meaning of the next question "tu arrives à pecho ?"

Tags: expressions

Someone asked me that, we were talking about sexual orientation and that kind of stuff but I didn't understand that question.

Answer (score 2):

*Pécho* is a French slang word for "seduce", mainly used in a sexual meaning (= "sleep with someone").
It is the [verlan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan) of *choper* which means *attraper* (to catch) and is used figurativlely to say "seduce".
Note that it is used as a verb and has only one form:

- *Je pécho*
- *Tu pécho*
- *Il pécho*

As for the plural form, "pécho" can only be used as a past participle: in the passé composé tense for instance:

- *Nous avons pécho*
- *Elles ont pécho*

etc.

Comment: When you say "slang" it chould be said new slang from "quartiers", not  traditional slang (say common around 1900). As I am over seventy, I had almost never heard this term and did not know its meaning (now I know it). Very low level element of language ; besides the way this kind of word could be used in a sentence is a true challenge....

Comment: As I know, it's relatively recent, a few decades at most. It's the "verlan" from "chopper", I'll add this in the answer.

Comment: I would be very suprised to hear *Nous avons pécho*. It sound really odd as it mixes formal (nous) and informal (pécho) elements. A bit like *s'il te plaît Madame!* . *On a pécho*  would be more likely.

Comment: @XouDo Indeed, it would actually make me laugh. *S'il te plait Madame/Monsieur* is uncommon but can be heard, I find it funny as well.