# What verbs have entered French in the past 30 years?

Tags: verbes, évolution-récente

I have a thirty-year-old list of thousands of French verbs, with translations. Is anyone aware of a list of French verbs that have entered the language more recently? I would like to ensure that the list of verbs is current.

Answer (score 1):

New verbs are almost all regular and belong to the first group (e.g.: *kiffer*, *liker*, *plussoyer*) so are simple to conjugate.

A weird exception is the *verlan* verb *[pécho](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44495/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-next-question-tu-arrives-%C3%A0-pecho/44500#44500)* which has only this form regardless of the tense / mode.

Comment: J'aurais pensé aussi aux nombreux verbes en -ave (ex: tchourave) qui restent également invariables.

Comment: @XouDo *Chouraver* est beaucoup plus ancien (attesté depuis plus de 60 ans - Frédéric Dard) et peut s'accorder (il a chouravé, vous chouravez, J’te chourav’rai ton blouson - Renaud).

Comment: Ouais, 1931 du romani _tchorav_ « voler » (DHLF/Rey). À part les trucs technologiques, je sais pas si on a tant de nouveaux verbes que ça dans le dernier quart de siècle au Québec...